# Netbeans Formatting within braces

Tags: netbeans

(Edited to correct the shortcut)

This seems to be a problem introduced in Netbeans 15 or 16.
When formatting code (CTRL-SHIFT-F) I'm finding the system is adding carriage returns after braces - even when I'm in a HTML file.

So for instance:

```
<input type='text' name='test{FIELD_COUNT}'>
```

If I hit CTRL-SHIFT-F it will format it as follows:

```
<input type='text' name='test{
FIELD_COUNT
}'>
```

This breaks my template.

Anyone know how to stop Netbeans doing this.  Remember this is a HTML file, not PHP or other language file.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

I can't seem to get the formatting right in my reply to placing it here.... have worked out it appears to be the ID attribute of HTML elements that is the issue.

So the following:

```
<input type="hidden" name="name{ONE}" value="" id='{ONE}'>
```

gets formatted to:

```
<input type="hidden" name="name{ONE}" value="" id='{
            ONE
        }'>
```

Yep... just checked this against my proper template and it is only the ID attribute incorrectly being formatted.  If I only had one token.... no biggie but when you've got 20 in a template you can't work with it.

Comment: Formatting source code (including HTML files) is `Alt+Shift+F` (see [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GObH3.png)), not `Ctrl+Alt+F`. I cannot recreate the behavior you are describing when using `Alt+Shift+F` - the HTML code is formatted as expected - braces stay on the same line.  `Ctrl+Alt+F` does not appear to perform any formatting.

Comment: If you look at the list of shortcuts in Tools > Options > Keymap, is your combination listed there?

Comment: I get the same result as Andrew: `Ctrl-Alt-F` is not an available shortcut for me (though I am using NetBeans 17). Navigate to **Tools > Options > Keymap**, click the **Shortcut** column header to sort by that column, scroll down the list of shortcuts to include the **Action** with the shortcut `Ctrl-Alt-F`, take a screenshot of the **Options** window, and then update your question with that screen shot.

Comment: ok.... the your replies reminded me that it doesn't do it on all tokens.  Only some.... so I just ran a test.  It appears that it's the ID attribute of a HTML element that gets modified. 

Here's the example I just triggered using the CTRL-SHIFT-F

`code`
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col s12'>
        <input type="hidden" name="name{ONE}" value="" id='{
            ONE
        }'>
    </div>
</div>
`code`

Comment: I see it now, thanks. You can format something as simple as `<div id="{}"></div>` and the newline will be inserted. I don't know how to change that behavior.

Comment: The NetBeans HTML formatter mostly just inherits the language agnostic _"All Languages"_ settings, which presumably explains your problems with curly braces. While it doesn't directly solve your problem, an approach that might help is to install the **External Code Formatters** plugin from **Tools > Plugins > Available Plugins**. Once that is installed a new tab named **External Formatter** will be created under **Tools > Options > Editor**. Perhaps using a different formatter will help? If so, post an answer.

Comment: I just installed the [**External Code Formatters for NetBeans**](https://github.com/funfried/externalcodeformatter_for_netbeans) plugin. The only alternative formatter it offers for HTML is _Jsoup HTML Code Formatter_, and that correctly handles your curly brace issue. However, it may have unwanted side effects. In my case it moved your `<input>` line up onto the same line as the preceding `<body>` tag. Perhaps tweaking with the configuration settings will resolve that, but I was unable to fix it.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I'll give it a shot.  Weird that this only started with either Netbeans 15 or 16.  Probably should log a bug report.

Comment: @Josh Did you ever manage to resolve this (annoying!) issue?

Comment: @skomisa nope.  It's been a while but I've just learned to live with it.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick update, since updating to Netbeans 18 I haven't seen this problem so I believe it is fixed by upgrading.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35123395)